# Why does "undefined method" on null:String in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

As i'm trying to show a specific data from has_many relation on a iteration

Why Rails shows undefined method  for Null:String and how do I fix it?

> NoMethodError (undefined method `rated' for "shop_date is not
>   null":String)

```
# controller Cast    
def cast    
  @products = Product.all
  @rating  = Product.joins(:shops).where(:shops => ('shop_date is not null').rated.average(:b_rating) || 0 )
end

# Model Shop
belongs_to :product

attr_accessible   :b_rating,:product_id

scope :by_participant, -> {  where('shop_date is not null').order('shop_date desc') }

scope :rated, -> {  where('b_rating is not null') }

def self.average_rating
  by_participant.rated.average(:b_rating) || 0
end

# Model Product
Has_many :shops
```

Comment: I guess you forgot to close brackets: `where(:shops => ('shop_date is not null'))`

Comment: Diodon, the brackets are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, simplest way is to user `group by` query:

```
# controller
@products = Product.all
products_ids = @products.collect(&:id)
@ratings = 
  Shop.where(product_id: products_ids).
    where('shop_date is not null').rated.
    group(:product_id).
    average(:b_rating)

# view
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  Rating: <%= @ratings[product.id] || 0 %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you IIya Lavrov but shows:

 
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to remove last bracket. Try updated version.

Comment: thank you IIya Lavrov. but the same.

the thing is: i'm trying to iterate the shops of product just with date not nil and get the rate that this shop received.

if i put the rating off the brackets rails interpret the rating as from product not from shop and when i put inside the brackets show that error related with the string.

Comment: I see what you need to do. Try new version, hope it will work.

Comment: thank you for your help IIya Lavrov.

but shows ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+))

and to be honest i have not idea what (0 for 1+) means

Comment: and one thing for use products_ids no need has_many though association?

Comment: i added average to your answer. and now shows NameError (uninitialized constant CastController::Shops)

Comment: I made one more change. May you try new version.

Comment: IIya Lavrov, thank you very much. but this uninitialized constant CastController::Shops, persists! and i can't understand. your code is right.

Comment: May be you have somewhere in your controller `Shops` instead of `Shop`?

Comment: a moment i'll check!

Comment: sorry i did not get what you said.

Comment: Your model class has name `Shop`. If you trying to call `Shops` (which is not defined) in your controller you will receive error `uninitialized constant CastController::Shops`. So try to find `Shops` in your code and replace with `Shop`

Comment: Man! what a thing Jesus! now the logs shows

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "shops.shop_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ..._rating is not null) GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY shop_date

Comment: Okay, i will do one more change

Comment: I changed solution a little bit. Now this mistake should gone

Comment: IIya Lavrov thank you very much for your help and persistence. but show the same error. seems that the error is caused because of grouping. if i remove the group(:product_id) ?

Comment: Without `group(:product_id)` it will make wrong result.

Comment: Ok, i removed the group(:product_id) and the logs shows:

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for #<BigDecimal:7ff439449410,'0.15E1',18(27)>)

related with   Rating: <%= @ratings[product.id] || 0 %>

Comment: and i removed the [product.id] || 0  to test and seems that worked. i'll test and put here

Comment: well, i don't know if worked. the rating shows. but seems the same to all products